# Email conditional logic after order complete in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to disable email notification when order total is equal to 0. It looks that my hook code works with this simple condition, but i don't know how to retrieve order details at this step.

```
$array = array('woocommerce_order_status_completed' );

function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $array ) {

if (0>1){    
 return $array;   
 }

}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions', 10, 1 );
```

Or should i use other hook for this? Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how much you know about programming, but you should know that `0` will **never** be greater than `1`, meaning your `$array` will never get returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove recipient from email notifications for new order based on order total. Use this piece of code and customize it based on order total for your requirement.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_new_order_cash_on_delivery_recipient', 10, 2 );
function wc_new_order_cash_on_delivery_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( 'cod' == $order->payment_method ) {
        $recipient .= ', john@example.com';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```